# Angular 2 HTTP post to Web API without [FromBody]

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, angular, asp.net-core, restangular

I have a sample Angular 2 code below.

```
 this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
 this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
 this.http.post('/api/todo/create', JSON.stringify(todo), this.options);
```

I also have an API action as seen below (ASP.NET Core)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("create")]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Todo todo)
{
    return this.Ok();
}
```

This code works but I am not comfortable in seeing the `[FromBody]` attribute in the parameter. I know that for Post requests, MVC reads it from the body. But, I have been using Restangular in AngularJS before and the parameter object is sent to an API without the `[FromBody]` attribute.

Is there a way to just pass the object  to the API action without using the `[FromBody]` attribute or reading the content of the request and then deserializing it to an object?

Comment: What was the HTTP request you used with Restangular / Angular1? I would say: sending your data in the payload within a POST request is the best way to do. The other possible option is to use query parameters but I don't really like this option...

Comment: What is the problem with `[FromBody]`?

Comment: nothing really. it's just that I'm not used to it and I'm curious why angular 2 can't do what restangular can. i guess I'll just study how restangular did it

Comment: I think sending data in the payload of a POST method is what you should do ;-) That said, the Angular2 HTTP support is low-level. I mean there is no high-level API for REST. You need to set headers by your own, hide the HTTP method you to use behind a JS / TypeScript method...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier ah sorry. was not able to read your first comment. im not exactly sure on how to do what you are saying but I'll study that. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the payload of a POST method is what you should do to send data to the server. You can choose the content type you want (JSON, url encoded form, ...).

That said, the Angular2 HTTP support is low-level. I mean there is no high-level API for REST. You need to set headers by your own, choose the HTTP method you want to use... I won't find something like Restangular in Angular2.

This link could help you:

- https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-of-the-best-practices-for-designing-a-RESTful-API